# Extracting address lines from a string separated by carriage returns report builder 3.0

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've found a suggestion to use the code below to extract the first line from a string which contains numerous address lines separated by carriage returns.

I'm using report builder 3.0, data source is an oracle database

SubStr(Table.Text, 1, decode(InStr(Table.Text, Chr(10)), 0, Length(Table.Text), InStr(Table.Text, Chr(10))) - 1)

The code correctly pulls out the first line...

How do I find the second line (after the first carriage return) and the third line (after the second carriage return) etc etc

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) with 4th parameter

```
select regexp_substr(text,'.*?'||chr(13))     as first_line,
       regexp_substr(text,'.*?'||chr(13),1,2) as second_line,
       regexp_substr(text,'.*?'||chr(13),1,3) as third_line
from t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33a78/13/0)

**EDIT:** By the way chr(10) is new line ASCII code, not a carriage return.